# Script to remove element while clientHeight < "size"

Tags: height, responsive

i'm wondering to make a script that dynamically removes a html element while the clientHeight < 600 px but rebuild it if it's >600px.

```
if (document.documentElement.clientHeight < 600) {
$(".section-intro").remove();
}
```

this is working so far but i want it to rebuild the removed element when the clientHeight is superior to 600px.
Could i use while else instead of if ?

Answer (score 0):

## Using CSS3 `@media` Rule

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  @media (max-height: 600px) {
    .section-intro {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div> Test 1 </div>
  <div class="section-intro" > Test 2 </div>
  <div> Test 3 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Using JavaScript

First create function, that will adjust visibility of HTML element. Secondly register that function as callback function with `$(document).ready( func )` and with `$(window).resize( func )`. This way your function will be called both when DOM is fully loaded, and when browser window is resized.

Here you have full working example of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function recalculateVisibility(jQuery) {
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight < 600) 
      $(".section-intro").hide();
    else 
      $(".section-intro").show();
  }

  $(document).ready(recalculateVisibility);
  $(window).resize(recalculateVisibility);
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div> Test 1 </div>
  <div class="section-intro" > Test 2 </div>
  <div> Test 3 </div>
</body>
</html>
```